# OpenReadCompleted Event is Not exist for HttpClient in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

The OpenReadCompleted Event is Exist in Wp8.0 With WebClient, But Not Exist in WP8.1 With HttpClient, What is the alternative to handle OpenReadCompleted Event for HttpClient in Wp8.1

```
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
 client.OpenReadCompleted += client_OpenReadCompleted;

 void client_OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
       MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream();
       GifDecoder gd = new GifDecoder();
       ImageTools.ExtendedImage img = new ImageTools.ExtendedImage();
       gd.Decode(img, e.Result);              //stream means image stream
       JpegEncoder png = new JpegEncoder();
       png.Encode(img, str);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpClient uses async methods, not events.

To use them, you must first mark your method as async. Then you can use the `GetStreamAsync` method to retrieve your stream:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient())
    {
        using (var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(yourUri))
        {
            MemoryStream str = new MemoryStream();
            GifDecoder gd = new GifDecoder();
            ImageTools.ExtendedImage img = new ImageTools.ExtendedImage();
            gd.Decode(img, stream);              //stream means image stream
            JpegEncoder png = new JpegEncoder();
            png.Encode(img, str);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you fire Button_Click Event for HttpClient

Comment: It's just a random method to show you how it works. Just put the code wherever you need, but don't forget to add the `async` keyword to the method (that's what I was trying to demonstrate)